# Expressing: "Send them over/up, please"

Tags: translation, verbs

This should be a rather straightforward (if a bit specific) bit of translation, but I cannot find a form that makes sense to me and gets corroborated by Google.

How would one translate the typical phrase structure:

> **Send him up/over** [to the nth floor, to my office etc]

Such as spoken to an office receptionist over the phone, to ask them to have a visitor go up to a certain floor/office.

More specifically, I am wondering what verbal form would be appropriate. My two inclinations were to go with either:

> 渡してください

... but I am pretty sure this could only apply to an object, not people.

Or:

> 行かせてください

... but this sounds more like "allow them/me to go" than "have them go" (and so do most usage examples I can find in Google).

Does anybody know what the definite way of expressing this would be?

Comment: can't you use 送る　for people too? 私に彼を送ってください。(?)

Comment: ◯◯さんに来てもらうようにお願いします。Otherwise, I would use 送る too. You can use 送る as well when you want to sent the person somewhere you are not at.

Comment: I am inclined to　some use of 送る　but in certain cases you might be able to use 派遣する [dispatch; send] as in 人材派遣業 [a temporary personnel service]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 会議室{かいぎしつ}にご[案内]{あんない}してください。 ([article from a business keigo website](http://www.koakishiki.com/renraku-plural/scene-4.html), [more examples](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%94%E6%A1%88%E5%86%85%E3%81%97))
>
> 会議室{かいぎしつ}にお[通]{とお}ししてください。 ([seen in a keigo manual (p.4)](http://www.idemitsu.co.jp/content/100149934.pdf), [more examples](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%8A%E9%80%9A%E3%81%97))

Causative form can work too, if you don't need to use keigo to the visitor:

> 会議室{かいぎしつ}で待{ま}たせておいてください。

I think 来させる is acceptable, but 行かせる sounds unnatural. This is not because of the verb form, but because of the semantics of 行く.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to poach the answer spot that yadokari and oldergod should get, but in my experience, 送る has definitely been used.

> 例：彼らをこちらに送って下さい。

Translated to "Please send them here."

> 例：彼らをこちらに呼んで下さい。

Would also be common, as in "Please call them here."

Comment: [[ I don't want to poach the answer spot that yadokari and oldergod should get, but in my experience, 送る has definitely been used. ]]

Why not?  They didn't bother to make their thoughts an answer.

Comment: poach on brother!

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud here, so I'm not sure of the exact contexts or nuances, but what about

> - 出す・送り出す　→　send : 使いを出す｜send a messenger
> - 向ける　→　〔行かせる〕send : 使者を向ける｜send a messenger ｟to｠
> - 遣【つか】わす・派遣する　→　人をある場所へ行かせる。英to dispatch : This one seems to be the wrong context
> - 招く　→　〔頼んで来てもらう〕: beckon ｟to｠
> - 寄せる　→　let ｟a person｠ come near : call on ｟a person｠
> - Others that seem **VERY** context-dependent and likely have particular nuances: 召す, 呼び寄せる, 近寄せる, 近付ける, 呼びつける, 召し寄せる, 引き渡す (seems very unlikely), 引き寄せる (also seems unlikely).